# Laravel sometimes generates a folder with the name of the image when saving it

Tags: laravel, php-7.2

I'm saving images on the laravel storage folder and basically all my code is this

```
      $image = $request->file('image');
      $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
      $name = Hash::make(Carbon::now()) . '.' .$ext;
      $image->storeAs('public/images/tmp', $name);
```

that save the image correctly like:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJbMU.png]

but sometimes it saves it inside a folder that has the same name: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ubR.png]

how can I avoid that?

Comment: Your Hash is Generating a `/` character. Don't use Hash function (UID or MD5 maybe?) or sanitize your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$image = $request->file('image');
$ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

```
  $name = str_replace('/',"",Hash::make(Carbon::now())) . '.' .$ext;
  $image->storeAs('public/images/tmp/', $name);
```

This once happened to me add a trailing forward slash at the end if tmp and use str_replace to replace all forward slash of the name

Answer (score 0):

Your Hash is Generating a `/` character which creates a folder. I would recommend using uuid instead of Hash:

```
      $image = $request->file('image');
      $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
      $name = uniqid() . '.' .$ext;
      $image->storeAs('public/images/tmp', $name);
```